# Undefined control sequence for inline math

Tags: math-mode

I was wondering what is wrong with the following line:

```
\(\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq{0}, \mathit{R} \times \mathit{N}}\)
```

I am trying to reproduce this:

[image: equation]

But get a:

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.542 ...egative matrices \(\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb
                                                  {R}^{\geq{0}, \mathit{R} \...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your error message, the line is very helpfully broken at the point where LaTeX ran into problems:

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.542 ...egative matrices \(\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb
                                                  {R}^{\geq{0}, \mathit{R} \...
```

In other words, `\mathbb` is your problem.

`\mathbb` requires the `amssymb` or `amsfonts` package.

If we add the required package, all is well.

However, there are a few things worth mentioning. The first is that `\geq` does not take an argument, so `\geq 0` is all you need. Second, in math mode, Roman letters like `R` and `N` are italic by default, so `\mathit{}` adds nothing but keystrokes and clutter.

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\(\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0, R \times N}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]